# Mapbox gl js Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, mapbox

So I installed mapbox gl js, webpack, and browserify which Mapbox gl js requires on mac osx.
However, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module error when I try to run the code on localhost.

All the modules are installed in Users/jbk/node-modules directory, and html file is in document folder.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>


<body>
<div id='map' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'></div>
<script>


    var mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyIjoic252cGxheWVyIiwiYSI6ImVmcG51V28ifQ.Dfj_Uwi6FXQu4AgmBaAESw';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I installed mapbox gl js, webpack, and browserify" — You don't appear to be **using** webpack or browserify though.

Comment: Your title says that you get an error because `require` is not defined (unsurprising since you are running in a browser without using webpack/browserify and not in Node.js) … but your question says the error is "Cannot use import statement outside a module" … and you have no `import` statement there.

Comment: I am fairly new to this, could you let me know what code to add or point me to the resource? Thanks,

Comment: Is there something specific you don't understand about the documentation for webpack or browserify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDN of mapbox instead of importing the mapbox.